# Closed as "Possible Duplicate"

Tags: support, closing, exact-duplicates

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86093/why-is-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1) question was closed as a "Possible Duplicate," which confuses me because I've never seen that before once the question has been closed.

Comment: Notice that the question was closed in 2011, back at the time when the duplicate banner used to be directly inserted into the question (and editable). This changed in 2013, based on what I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280798/editing-duplicate-banner-edited-into-the-text-of-the-question) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/should-users-be-allowed-to-remove-the-possible-duplicate-links-on-closed-quest/166733#166733). See also: [Of which question is this question duplicate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17304)

Comment: The question linked to has now been edited to remove the "Possible Duplicate" text.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche yes, I did that, but unfortunately the linked duplicate doesn't appear in the notice *below* the post (which I expected it to do).

Comment: I suppose we could reopen and reclose as duplicate to get the *modern* display.  Is it worth it?